# Migrate owncloud data+db to Ubuntu Snappy?

Tags: ubuntu-core, migration, owncloud-server

I'm about to get my hands on a Pioneer Raspberry Pi drive running Owncloud 9 on Ubuntu Snappy 16.04. I want to move my old owncloud instance to this new device, I just don't know how.

Currently I'm running Ubuntu Server 15.04 on an old PC. Having a few hundred GB of files in there. Now I want to move all of it to the new Raspberry Pi based Ubuntu Snappy system. All files and configuration.

I have no experience with Ubuntu Snappy - yet - but from what I've understood about the new packaging paradigm I might come into trouble about an otherwise trivial migration of data.

Do I still access to mysql so that I can import the old db, as well some kind of access to be able to migrate the old files? Snappy seem to have SSH, so rsync is there, but is there something that I need to think about otherwise about the file migration?

Cheers, 
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this won't be terribly easy, not really because of Snappy but because ownCloud doesn't help you at all (I think it should have a method of doing this), so you need to do it yourself. There are three things you'll have to deal with: the config, the data, and the database.

#### The config

While you can do this via `occ`, I actually suggest you do it by hand so you don't overwrite some values upon which the snap is relying (e.g. the out-of-application apps folder, etc.). The `config.php` is located in `/var/lib/snaps/owncloud.canonical/current/owncloud/config/`. If you want to use `occ` anyway, note that the command on Snappy is `sudo owncloud.occ`.

#### The data

You were spot-on with this one-- rsync from original to new. The data directory is `/var/lib/snaps/owncloud.canonical/current/owncloud/data/`.

#### The database

Unfortunately, you're going to run into trouble here-- the snap itself doesn't expose a mysql client, though maybe it should, knowing this use-case. Feel free to [log a bug](https://github.com/kyrofa/owncloud-snap/issues) on that.

#### Oh, the apps

If you have apps you want to transfer, put then in `/var/lib/snaps/owncloud.canonical/current/owncloud/apps/`

Comment: Thank you very much. It was especially the database that I was afraid of being not that simple. The other parts should be pretty straight forward, thanks to your info. I will very likely log a bug about the mysql client and then see what I can do. I will update this question once I have anything new. Thanks again!